# Java the best way to specify place of a single word in file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

Basically, a problem that I went into has many solutions but the only one that came to my mind is dirty and will end up with a lot of boilerplate code.
Let's say we have a log file with lines like this.

```
127.0.0.1   Amigo   30.08.2012 16:08:13 LOGIN   OK <br>
192.168.100.2   Pete Tyson  30.08.2012 16:08:40 COMPLETE_TASK 15    OK <br>
146.34.15.5 Eduard Bentley  03.01.2014 03:45:23 LOGIN   OK
```

What is the best solution if log file can dynamically change and not every line has same length and I would want to take username out of it?

Edit:

```
 private int atWhatPlaceDateIs(String[] line) {
    if(line[4].contains(":") && line[3].contains("."))
        return 1;
    else if (line[3].contains(":") && line[2].contains("."))
        return 0;

    return -1;
}

if(atWhatPlaceDateIs(line) == 1)
     date = line[3] + " " + line[4];
else if(atWhatPlaceDateIs(line) == 0)
     date = line[2] + " " + line[3];
```

That's what I did with date, it always is at 2-3 or 3-4 index

Comment: I think you can use a regular expression, to separate parts of the line.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your attempt (the relevant code) and where you are encountering problems.

Comment: *is dirty and will end up with a lot of boilerplate code* - post your code and we can make suggestions. I don't see being too complex.

Comment: I just made an edit

Comment: I thought about doing the same thing with names using [A-Za] regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider the use of a regular expression. There are tons of tutorials on the web to accomplish what you describe.

This tutorial [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) should provide you with enough to get started.

Comment: @KamilK if you believe my answer to be helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer by using the green check to the left of the answer. Others may also find this useful.